# pass value to jquery dialog form

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-ui-dialog

I need a dialog window to popup with a form and pass a value to this form. I have attempted several approaches to this problem but I have been unable to do so. I have searched all over and nothing seems to work.

This is my latest attempt:

```
  var message="variable";

 .click(function() {
 $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
 $('<input>').attr({
    type: 'text',
    id: 'hidden-input",
    value: message,
    name: 'bar'
 }).appendTo("#dialog-form");
```

If i put the append inside the dialog the popup stops working (i think i dont know how to do this properly)

Comment: Also 'hidden-input" starts with a single quote and ends with a double one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I *think* you're looking for something like this:

```
<script>
$(function(){
   var message = "variable";

   $("#showDialog").click(function() {
      $("#hidden-input").val(message);

      $("#dialogForm").dialog("open");
   });
});
</script>

<button id="showDialog">Show Dialog</button>

<div id="dialogForm">
<input type="text" id="hidden-input" name="bar"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

I use script entirely for dialog handling (I think it is cleaner):

http://jsfiddle.net/fE6q2/

html:

```
Default firstname:<br>
<input type='text' id="default_firstname"/>
<br><br>
<button onclick='on_create_form_clicked()'>create form</button>
```

javascript:

```
function on_create_form_clicked()
{
    var html =
       "<div>" +
          "Firstname:<br>" +
          "<input type='text' class='firstname'/>" +
          "<br/><br/>" +
          "Lastname:<br>" +
          "<input type='text' class='lastname'/>" +
          "<br/><br/>" +
          "<button class='ok'>ok</button>" +    
       "</div>";

    var div = $(html);

    var default_firstname = $('#default_firstname').val();
    div.find('.firstname').val(default_firstname);        

    div.find('.ok').click(function()
    {
        div.dialog('close');

        var firstname = div.find('.firstname').val();
        var lastname = div.find('.lastname').val();

        alert("firstname was " + firstname
            + " and lastname was " + lastname);        
    });

    div.dialog(
    {
        title:"Enter firstname and lastname",
        close: destroy_this_dialog
    });
}

function destroy_this_dialog(event, ui)
{
  $(this).dialog("destroy");
  $(this).remove();
}
```

Comment: Both solutions work like a charm. I had actually attempted Calvin's approach but I must have been doing something wrong because it didnt work before. I need to form to call a php script to enter the data into a db hence I need to pass an ID to the form. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Nice! Dont forget to mark Calvins answer as the solution then.

Comment: Cleaner solution and it worked in the scenario that i am using.