# How to pass a value to dialog widget

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function click1(a) {
     var srcdivid =$(a).closest('div').attr('id');
     $("#pagetemplate").dialog("open"); return false;
}
```

Here in this function I get the value of `srcdivid`. I want to pass `srcdivid` value to  `$("#pagetemplate").dialog("open");`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one hidden input with id="test1" in model div and write the value to it then it will show once popup visible

```
function click1(a) {
 var srcdivid =$(a).closest('div').attr('id');
 $('#hidden-input').val(srcdivid);
 $("#pagetemplate").dialog("open"); return false;
```

}

```
<div id="pagetemplate">
    <input type="text" id="hidden-input" name="bar"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Refer this link's answer you will get better idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317953/pass-value-to-jquery-dialog-form

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
    $('button').click(function (e) {
        var srcdivid = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            open: function(event, ui) {
                $(this).append('<h3>' + srcdivid + '</h3>');    
            }
        });
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/vf37a3jv/1/)